# Disabling Android Keyboard's 'Go' Button for WebView Text Entry

Tags: java, android, jquery-mobile, form-submit

I am developing an Android application that uses a WebView pointed at a jQueryMobile-based site. Normally, disabling the 'Go' button on the soft keyboard is as simple as adding `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to the control's XML tag. In the case of WebViews however, this doesn't do the trick.

How can I disable the 'Go' button from automatically doing a form submission, or alternatively to simply replace it with the 'Done' button, like `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` would for an EditText?

Comment: This issue is plaguing me. I have yet to find a workaround, and nothing in the Android dev specs even allude to such functionality. I can't tell if this is an actual oversight by the Android development team or just something that they forgot to spec. Either way, I would think it would be standard to want to control the IME's configuration.

Comment: More interestingly, it would be nice if there would be a simple way to set the 'Go' button to something else like 'Next' or 'Go' or 'Search' depending on which input field the user is currently on. If I have a fieldset with multiple fields, I usually want the 'Next' label, whereas for the last input field I'd like to have 'Go'. But I guess it's not done that simply; would need to do it with javascript and CustomWebClient passed to the WebView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may stop submitting form by putting the `onsubmit` event of the form.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more detailed answer that uses the method alluded to by Vikas.

Since the problem is that your form is submitting, you can add an onSubmit attribute to your form element that runs JavaScript to determine if your form should be submitted.

Below is the form that you don't want to submit:

```
<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return doNothing()">
    <!-- Elements included in the form -->
</form>
```

And include this script that returns false which keeps your form from submitting.

```
<script>
function doNothing()
{
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Now, when you press Go after entering text into your text input field, the keyboard will simply collapse without submitting the form.

This could also be used to check for errors in your form. See the webpage below:
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html

Comment: I would like to stop enter key from submitting but i would like my submit button to work...