# Disable key "GO" in android keyboard inside webview

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

After googling a lot, I cannot handle this issue:

[image]

ISSUE:
I have a webview that has a Login and password.
When I press Login, in the keyboard appears the key "GO". When the user types his login, and GO is pressed, the form is sended without password.

How can I change the Key GO for NEXT or RETURN, without send the form?

About:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Doesn't work because is not a textView.

P.S: I cannot change the HTML code. :(

Any ideas?

Comment: The imeOptions are the only way to change it.  Since you're a webpage, the browser sets that based off the type.  You can try changing the type of the input field in the HTML.  If you really can't change the HTML, then what type of answer were you expecting?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time.  If this is the only solution, i will try to change the html code. Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Android Keyboard's 'Go' Button for WebView Text Entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249934/disabling-android-keyboards-go-button-for-webview-text-entry)