# Disable SoftKeyboard inside a WebView

Tags: android, webview

I know this is a common question but I can't find here and on Google, a functioning solution.

I have a WebView in my android app with a JSF page inside with a simple DatePicker component:

```
<p:calendar value="#{patientHealthDataView.dateFrom}" id="popupButtonDateFrom" showOn="button" class="tableCalendarText"/>
```

that show a Popup with calendar.

Thanks to this command, I manage to make the popup works:

```
WebView view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.statistics);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Unfortunally, when I click on input text or the button to show the calendar's popup, the focus goes to Input Text and Android show its keyboard hiding the calendar.

I've tried several solution. The last one was this:

```
 view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            hideSoftKeyboard(v);
            return false;
        }
    });

public void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

This code, as suggested by Android Studio, raise a Null Pointer Exception on:

```
activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken()
```

Other solutions says to insert a special command in manifest but I want to block the keyboard only in the WebView.

Any suggests?

Comment: Have you tried `inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webView.getWindowToken(), 0);` where `webView` is your `WebView view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.statistics);` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just tried. Unfortunally this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like the best "hack" yet is to know when the keyboard has been deployed, and hide it from there. Solutions can be found on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/17672116/4706693

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Android Keyboard's 'Go' Button for WebView Text Entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249934/disabling-android-keyboards-go-button-for-webview-text-entry)

Comment: try these hacks  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548564/6584867

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add following code in main(parent) layout in your layout.xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Hope it will work.

and set following property in your webview

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: My WebView partent tag is a LinearLayout. I've tried using your code as below:
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
but it doesn't work.
I've also tried with "false" in focusableInTouchMode but its the same. The Keyboard Still Shows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was using a text input with a datetimepicker:

HTML: input type="text" placeholder="Birth Date" id="some_id" name="some_id" value="" required

JQuery: 
$('#some_id').datetimepicker({format: \'YYYY-MM-DD\'});

However this caused issues because the soft keyboard would pop up when you tried to select a date. I then tried to fix it with the below:

HTML: input type="text" placeholder="Birth Date" id="some_id" name="some_id" value="" onfocus="blur();" required

This worked but it took way too long to actually open the calendar, but at least the soft keyboard wasn't popping up. This is just to show you what I tried at first.

MY SOLUTION:
input type="date" placeholder="Birth Date" id="some_id" name="some_id" value="" required

All I had to do was to change the input type from "text" to "date" and remove the jquery line.

Hope this helps someone.  :)